# What is this iridescent goo?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm curious about this rainbow colored, iridescent goo that's littering the floor of the Barrow Temple in Skyrim. It looks poisonous and so for awhile I was trying to avoid it, thinking that it was some sort of trap. Then, I got curious and stepped around in it and nothing happened. Does this serve any purpose other than to look pretty? Any idea what it might actually be?

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you look up, you should see a hanging lantern. It looks to be oil that has leaked from the lantern. If you knock the lantern into the oil, or shoot some magic fire at the oil, the oil slick will catch fire and burn until the oil is consumed.

Comment: That's one of the most awesome things I've ever heard. Excuse me while I go light all the skeletons on fire :)

Comment: There's some in the tutorial dungeon too, in the cavern with the river and bridges. I learned that it was flammable the fun way.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - by accidentally setting it on fire and dying horribly? :p

Comment: @spugsley Almost! But no, it was regular fun, not Dwarf Fortress Fun. An enemy was standing in it when I blasted them with flame.